# How to add contact shortcut to Home screen in android programatically

Tags: android-contacts, shortcut

I succeed in install/uninstall the shortcut for the application but I would like to add the shortcut for the selected contact and it should be like Quick contact badge. I checked the default source but the main part of the create shortcut is hidden. So, anyone could help me on this..

Thanks,

Jetti